# American marrying British fiance in Gibraltar on UK tourist visa

Tags: uk, us-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, weddings, gibraltar

I am a US citizen in the UK on a tourist visa wanting to marry my British fiance. I did not get a Marriage Visitor Visa prior to this trip because we had not been planning on getting married, but we are considering it now that I am in the UK. The terms of my visa prohibit marriage as a tourist in Britain but does that include the UK territory Gibraltar? I don't want to have an issue in future returning to UK. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an actual UK Standard Visitor Visa or did you enter visa-free as a US citizen?

Comment: Do you intend to settle in the UK after your marriage, or return to the US?

Comment: You can still give notice of your intention to get married in the UK, even if you don’t have a Marriage Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships

Comment: This American lady married her British partner in Gibraltar in Dec '18. Hopefully some info here that you can follow-up:   https://sarahlaviajera.com/2019/10/22/how-to-get-married-in-gibraltar-as-an-american-2019/

Comment: @canonacer although she is wrong about the barriers to getting married in the UK or US, both of which would have been possible, had they wanted to do it, without needing a fiancee visa in either case.  She did mention other reasons in addition to the supposed barriers, so maybe they would have made the same decision had they understood the situation correctly.

Comment: As a self-governing British Overseas Territory, Gibraltar does not form part of the UK. http://www.gibraltarlawoffices.gov.gi/gibraltar-constitution Getting married in Gibraltar https://www.gibraltar.gov.gi/civil-status-registration-office/marriages-civil-partnerships should not in itself result in any issues with UK Immigration on future visits, providing you continue to meet the suitability and eligibility criteria for non- visa national visitors each time you apply for permission to enter on arrival https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

Comment: @RobertColumbia from the point of view of getting married in the UK (and certainly not in Gibraltar, for that matter) I don't think it makes a difference whether the US fiancee has an actual Standard Visitor Visa or visa-free leave to enter.  Is there some difference that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

> I did not get a Marriage Visitor Visa prior to this trip because we had not been planning on getting married, but we are considering it now that I am in the UK.

You *can* get married in the UK on a standard visitor visa.  What you cannot do, and what you need a Marriage Visitor Visa for, is *to enter the UK with the intention of getting married there.*  But you didn't do that.

Thanks to [Traveller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/60926/traveller) for posting a [relevant link](https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships) in a comment.  From that page:

> If you do not have a marriage visitor visa or family visa
>
> You can still give notice of your intention to get married or form a civil partnership but the immigration authorities at the Home Office will be told.
>
> The Home Office might:
>
> - ask questions about you and your relationship - if this happens you may need to wait up to 70 days before getting married or forming a civil partnership
> - decide not to approve your notice - if this happens you cannot get married or form a civil partnership in the UK

The point of this is to identify and prevent immigration fraud.  If you can show that you don't intend to settle in the UK in the immediate future, the Home Office should not delay or prevent your wedding.

Furthermore, as explained in a [page](https://sarahlaviajera.com/2019/10/22/how-to-get-married-in-gibraltar-as-an-american-2019/) helpfully linked by [canonacer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/91355/canonacer), if you still want to get married in Gibraltar, it seems as though you can do that:

> There are no residency or nationality requirements.

I note, however, that there are two problems with that page:

1. As noted above, a fiancee visa would not have been necessary to marry in the UK, because the couple were not planning to settle in the UK.  A Marriage Visitor Visa would have sufficed (and, as explained, is not necessary in your case).
2. It is similarly not fraudulent for a non-US national to marry a US citizen in the US while in visitor status when the couple plan to leave the country before the expiration of the non-US spouse's status.

In both of the above cases, though, some applicants might have difficulty proving their intent to leave the country after getting married, which could lead to refusal of a UK Marriage Visitor Visa or, for the US, refusal of entry as a visitor.  That seems unlikely in the case described in the article, but it is something that couples should consider, especially if they haven't yet put down firm roots in a foreign place of residence.